# Ajax success function not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript function with a ajax call. It reaches safely to the controller with no problem. But when the controller give back the result into json format, then I have not get the data in view page.

Below the code snippets:
Controller Action Method:

```
public JsonResult GetContactDetails(string contactId)
{
    Contact objContact = _contactService.Get(contactId.TryToInt());
    return Json( objContact, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Javascript Method:

```js
function GetContactDetails(contactId, designation, mobile) {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("GetContactDetails", "Clients")',
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            data: {contactId:contactId},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                alert("Yes");
                debugger;
                
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you get `alert` in `error`? Any error in `console`?

Comment: Yes error method is fired. And every time I get the alert of error.@Tushar

Comment: And what does `console` has to say?

Comment: This is the console error message I have got. "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).onChange is not a function" @Tushar

Comment: $("#Contacts_@(Model.Guid)__Contact").change(function() {
                    debugger;
                    var contactId = $(this).val();
                    var designation = "Contacts_@(Model.Guid)__Contact_Designation";
                    var mobile = "Contacts_@(Model.Guid)__Contact_Mobile";
                    GetContactDetails(contactId, designation, mobile);

                    

                });   from this snippets of code the GetContactDetails function is fired. I have Used $().change() method. @Tushar

Comment: Please update code snippets in question itself, instead of pasting them in comments.

Comment: chage the error to: error: function(xhr, status, error) and tell us additional details about the error
PS: also, put more effort into formatting your code

Comment: I think that you should use post instead of get. Add [HttpPost] attribute to the controller class, change the return to retrun Json(objContact) and in the ajax call change the type to type: 'POST'

Comment: What do you get if you call the action directly as the url in the browser?

Comment: is your javascript method in a javascript file or in the view?  Because '@Url.Action()' will not work in a javascript file

Comment: Its a cshtml view. @MarkOlsen

Comment: I have already used [HTTPPOST]. But there is exactly same result I got. @SvetoslavPetrov

Comment: When I use error: function(xhr, status, error) instead of error:, then I have got the below message "parsererror [object Object]SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data." @MihaiTibrea

Comment: @Sonkhocil I see no problem with your code as your provided. Please try this [sample here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LEgO3o) and see what differs with your version.

Comment: My problem is solved. There is some problem with my model. The model I have used is too much complex. Because its inherited from some other base classes. When I have made a view model. And put data from my original model to view model and send the view model to the view then it works fine. Thanks everyone for your support.